# How to remove a folder named ${env.CATALINA_HOME} from an Subversion repo

Tags: svn, environment-variables

I pulled a stupid and accidentally committed a folder named ${env.CATALINA_HOME} to my subversion repo. I tried doing an svn rm /path/to/${env.CATALINA_HOME} but it says "bad substitution" which I'm guessing means that it cant figure out why i'm using ${} notation in the path. I also tried surrounding the path in quotes, to no avail.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a Bourne shell, use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a shell question than a subversion question...you have a couple of
options.

1) Enclose the path in single quotes instead of double quotes -- this suppresses the variable substitution.

or

2) Escape the $ with a backslash: \$

Both options should work in just about any shell variant -- Bourne shell,
bash, csh, ksh, zsh...